# VBA Autofilter customer number formatted column?

Tags: excel, formatting, autofilter, vba

So I have this file with 60K rows. My data analyst people need to go through this and pick out about 30K rows. This occurs every few days.

They have 1 sheet with the 60K rows, and they have another with the 30k rows to pull out. I put them together in one workbook. then what I did was write a macro that took all the values in the column they are using for finding the correct rows (It's column A, an ID column) and put those values in an array.

code:

```
        'in this code the active sheet is the one with the 30k rows to pull
        For i = 1 To numrows 
            killArray(index) = ActiveCell.Offset(i - 1, 0).value2 'did research and value2 is fastest
            index = index + 1

        Next
```

and then I used the autofilter:

```
'here the sheet with all 60k rows is active
Cells(1, IdCol).entireColumn.autofilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array(killArray), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

So that then takes all 30k Id's puts them into an array, and filters the sheet with all rows using the array. Then the data guys can briefly look over it, and delete all of those rows.

now, they have decided they really want to use a custom format for the ID column. all id's are between 1 and 6 digits. so from 1 - 999999. the data guys have decided they like formatting it so that ALL id's are 6 digits, with leading 0's. so id 1 would be 000001.

the problem is when I use .value to put the id's into the kill array, it gets the id without formatting. so id 000001 would be just 1. this would be fine except the autofilter doesnt work now. because id - 1, does not match id - 000001. I've done some checking, and I found I could use `killArray(index) = ActiveCell.Offset(i - 1, 0).text` but during the course of my research (and testing) I've discovered this is VERY slow.

Is there a way to have autofilter ignore the formatting? I've done lots of reseach but I have only managed to find people having issues with dates. I don't have an issue with dates

Comment: it's probably quicker to use Format: `killArray(index) = Format(ActiveCell.Offset(i - 1, 0).value2, "000000")`. probably also a lot quicker to load the range into a variant in one pass and then loop through the array formatting the elements

Comment: if I load the entire column into a variant array in one statement, doesn't that make it a 2D array? Could I use a 2D array for the autofilter?

Comment: no but you can use `application.transpose(range.value2)` to get a 1d array :-)

Comment: sweet :) I shall research / try that :) make an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably get better performance with

```
killArray = application.transpose(some_range.value2)
for n = lbound(killarray) to ubound(killarray)
    killarray(n) = Format(killarray(n), "000000")
next n
```

or even

```
Dim killArray
Dim somerange As Range
Set somerange = Range("A2:A10000")
With somerange
    killArray = Application.Transpose(Evaluate("INDEX(TEXT(" & .Address & ",""000000""),)"))
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a need for speed, first remove the un-necessary loop:

```
For i = 1 To numrows
    killArray(Index) = ActiveCell.Offset(i - 1, 0).Value2
Next
```

This can be replaced by:

```
killArray(Index) = ActiveCell.Offset(numrows - 1, 0).Value2
```

Comment: I shoulda specified, `killarray` is an array with 30k index's, one for each row in that pull sheet. so it loops through each row in the pull sheet and adds each row into a spot in the array, so wouldn't your solution just run once adding the last element in that sheet into the array?

Comment: You are not changing **Index** in the loop, you are only changing **i** ......so if **Index** happened to be 768, you would be changing **Index(768)** 30,000 times!

Comment: *facepalm* you're correct, I left that Line out. `index = index + 1` is in my code I just missed it in here.